# Regular Expression partially not match a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an object like this:

```
"info" : {
 "interval": "Mon-Fri 8-11",
"interval1": "Mon-Fri 17-20",
"intervalSat": " Sat 8-11",
"intervalSat2": "Sat 17-20"
}
```

And I want to find out how many times interval or intervalSat have occurred regardless of their index. My sample code is here but it does not work correctly.

```
function countAccurrencies(info, keyName) {
 var regex = new RegExp('(' + keyName + ')', 'gi');
var counter = 0;
for (var key in info) {
    if (key.match(regex)) {
        counter++;
    }
}
console.log("count---------  " + counter)
return counter;
  }
```

the output of countAccurrencies(info,'interval') ---> count =4 which is wrong but I expect count =2
the out of countAccurrencies(info,'intervalSat)---> count =2 and it is right
It would be great if someone guides me. thanks.

Comment: if (key.match(regex) && key !=='inerval') {      -- is inerval a type-o?

Comment: @ sniperd, i have edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding regex in this case.

`(interval)` will match anystring that contains "interval" whether that is "interval10" or "10interval".

If your "keys" are structured as "key", "key1", "key2" etc. then you should match on the "key" portion plus digits:

`keyName + '[0-9]?$'` is the regex you want. [0-9]?$ says that the last character in the string is a number 0-9 then the end of the string OR if no number then just the end of the string.

```js
var info = {
  "interval": "Mon-Fri 8-11",
  "interval1": "Mon-Fri 17-20",
  "intervalSat": " Sat 8-11",
  "intervalSat2": "Sat 17-20"
};


function countAccurrencies(info, keyName) {
  var regex = new RegExp(keyName + '[0-9]?$', 'gi');
  var counter = 0;
  for (var key in info) {
    if (key.match(regex)) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  console.log("count---------  " + counter)
  return counter;
}

countAccurrencies(info, "interval");
countAccurrencies(info, "intervalSat");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working, you're checking if 'interval' exists in the string and of course 'intervalSat' includes the word interval. You need a different method, or a regex that just allows numbers after the keyName. I'd also suggest not using "object" as a variable name, and I believe you have a typo "inerval", though I'm not sure that logic does what you expect.

Comment: Liam MacDonald, I edited the typo. I don't care about the numbers and it is not in my interest. I just want to know how many times does this word 'intervalSat' repeated or 'interval'